# Excel: IF (cell C2 is not anywhere in column A OR not anywhere in column B) then return cell C2 in Cell D2

Tags: excel, match

I have checked alot of `INDEX` and `MATCH` formula but can't nail this if someone can point me in the right direction to compare one cell in the C column against all cells in Column A and Column B and if it is in neither enter C2 in D2 so I have a list of numbers not in either column A or B.

So the idea is I check every C column cell against the other two columns and show the C cells that are in netiher.

Hopefully this pseudo code helps explain:
IF (cell C2 is not anywhere in column A OR not anywhere in column B) then return cell C2 in Cell D2

This one works for one column check:
`=INDEX(C$2:C$23,MATCH(C2,A$2:A$23,0))`

but I need two column check but the below does not work for me as it just says #N/A even for the row that was working for the single column check formula above.  I I wondering if I can put an OR in the  middle of the two matches or maybe you can suggest it a different way.

`=INDEX(C$2:C$23,MATCH(C2,A$2:A$23,0),MATCH(C2,B$2:B23,0))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Excel `AND()` and `OR()` functions.  Also, consider marking the solution you liked as accepted...

Answer (score 1):

Try using COUNTIF like this

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:B$23,C2)=0,C2,"")`

or if columns are not adjacent

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$23,C2)+COUNTIF(B$2:B$23,C2)=0,C2,"")`

Those will return C2 value if it's not in either column....otherwise a blank

....if you really want to use MATCH try this version....

`=IF(COUNT(MATCH(C2,A$2:A$23,0),MATCH(C2,B$2:B$23,0))=0,C2,"")`

Comment: that will work OK as long as C8 can't appear in the same position in each range, e.g if A2 = B2 = C8 and C8 doesn't appear anywhere else that version will give you an error. If that's an issue try `=INDEX(C$2:C$23,MATCH(TRUE,(C8=$A$2:$A$23)+(C8=$B$2:$B$23)>0,0))`

Answer (score 0):

And one more version using `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C$2,$A:$A,1,0)),ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C$2,$B:$B,1,0))),"",$C$2)
```